# Count how many unique Column A entries also have specific values in Column B AND Column C

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a SQL table with three columns: ID, Item, Variable.

- **ID** is a unique user ID (Ex. '12345').
- **Item** is a numbered item for a specific setting parameter (Ex. '20'
  for Notification preferences; and '150' for Color Theme).
- **Variable** is the option the user has for the above setting (Ex. '0'
  for no notifications; and '1' for Dark).

I want to find how many users have two pairs of settings. For example, how many users have:
`Notifications: Off AND Color Mode: Dark`. Or as that would look in the database:
`20 = '0' AND 150 = '1'`.

Individually, I can run the following to get a count of how many users have Notifications: Off, and also how many users have Color Theme: Dark.

Notificaitons Off:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `settings` WHERE item = '20' AND variable = '0'
```

Dark Mode On

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `settings` WHERE item = '150' AND variable = '1'
```

But how can I find how many users have BOTH Notifications: Off and Color Theme: Dark (item 20 = '0' AND item 150 = '1')?

So in the table below, I'd expect my result to be '2' as user 78 and user 81 both have Item 20 = 0 AND Item 150 = 1.

| id | item | variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **78** | **20** | **0** |
| **78** | **150** | **1** |
| 79 | 20 | 1 |
| 79 | 150 | 1 |
| 80 | 20 | 1 |
| 80 | 150 | 0 |
| **81** | **20** | **0** |
| **81** | **150** | **1** |

Comment: Please supply some sample data and desired results (as text, not an image).

Comment: @Stu Table example added to original post.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your sample data, and assuming users can have a single row per item you could do

```
select count (*) from (
    select id
    from t
    where (item=20 and variable = 0) or (item = 150 and variable = 1)
    group by id
    having Count(*) = 2
)t;
```

Comment: This is perfect and something I'll learn from with other needs in the future. Thanks so much @Stu.

Comment: is there a simple alteration to this to extra the ID's that match this? For example, running the function would result in "78. 81"? This isn't a direct need but I'm thinking of ways to expand this in the future.

Comment: Presumably you just need the inner query in that case

Comment: Yep! That's all it took. Amazing. Thanks again!

Comment: You didn't ask for delimited list of IDs however look at `GROUP_CONCAT()` if that's actually what you need.